# Extract Service and Model using CoreData to a Cocoapod

Tags: ios, objective-c, macos, core-data, cocoapods

This is my Setup:

1. A Mac App and iOS App should both consume the same service
2. I am using CoreData
3. I want to put the shared code into a private cocoapod (Model classes + Service)
4. For communication with the Webservice I use RestKit

It is now not clear to me how exactly I should go about when extracting the functionality to a shared CocoaPod and I am wondering if there are any best practises on those issues:

- Should the Manged Object Model be part of the cocoapod
- How do I handle image data (`UIImage` for iOS and `NSImage` for the Mac)
- Will the iOS and the OSX Pod respectively be some sort of sub-spec or will that be the same Pod for different platforms